# How to protect mp4 file on IsolatedStorage of Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, mp4, copy-protection

I don't know how to protect video file on IsolatedStorage.
I encrypted mp4 file then I have to decrypt it to play on MediaElement.
After decrypted mp4 file can not be protected.

What will I do to protect mp4 file absolutely?

Comment: You should define what you actually mean by "protect". Are you talking about DRM?

Comment: Yeah DRM, I just want any methods to protect my mp4 file on IsolatedStorage and don't want that file is played on another device.
How to?